# File download control - delete file without validation?

Tags: file-upload, download, xpages

Hello XPages programmers.

I work on a simple XPages File Library.
To achieve that i use FileUpload control with FileDownload control.

When i create a new file, i enter its name, and select a file.
I set that uploading a file won't activate a validation, so i can attach a file without a specified name. Additionally i set it to do fullrefresh, so uploading a file takes place in an instant and a file is visible in FileDownload control.

Problem occurs, when i want to delete that attachment using garbage icon of FileDownload - i can't set it to run without walidation.

Is there any workaround avaiable?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which Domino Version are you using?

Comment: 8.5.3 for Domino Server and 9 for Domino Designer

Comment: With Domino 8.5.3 you can use this code: http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1019 But the IBM changed the objects, that's why this won't work with ND9 anymore (Server)

Comment: A workaround might be to use a repeat control to show the list of all attached files. In that repeat you can add an action to every row that calls some server side (Java/ SSJS) code to retrieve the document and remove the attachment.

Comment: Thanks for ideas, i think i will just add a button that deletes all attachments as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the workaround Mark Leusink suggested - created a simmilar button (used image from filedownload control) and then set it for full refresh with process data without validation property.

Code in JSSS

```
function deleteAttachments()
{
    var attList = dDocument.getAttachmentList("Document_Attachment");
    for(var i=0; i<attList.size(); i++) 
    {
        var att:String = attList[i];
        dDocument.removeAttachment("Document_Attachment", att.getName() );
    }
}
```

Surely it can be used for delete a specific attachment by getting attachment name from rowdata in a repeater and use DATASOURCE.removeAttachment method.

Thanks for your support!